# Yii2 error handler dies ugly on non-object calls

Tags: php, yii, error-handling, yii2, die

Can anyone have any idea, what can cause Yii2 error handler to halt correctly on following line:

```
echo $missing;
```

(assuming, that `$missing` is null) and display correctly "*Undefined variable: missing...*" notice. And in the same time "die" totally on following line:

```
echo $missing->noneExisting();
```

and display (return) completely blank page instead of correct error message?

I have a very strange troubles with Yii2 error handler ever since I started coding in Yii2. Above code is one of examples. Another one is, that redeclaring `Yii` namespace in migration [causes command-line console to die ugly, instead of displaying proper fatal error](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8206).

[I've been told](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8206#issuecomment-96988544), that this problem is caused by my PHP configuration. But I found it hard to believe -- mainly because:

- I haven't changed *anything* in my XAMPP structure, `php.ini` content etc. for past many, many months, I'm actually still using old-good 1.8.1 version of XAMPP (versioned  without compliance to PHP version),
- all metioned problems started about month ago, when I started coding in Yii2 and happens *only* in Yii2-powered apps -- I can't reproduce any of above mentioned problems in any of my Yii1-powered projects.

I agree, that this must be something in my local installation of PHP, because I have tested all of these examples in freshly-new installed XAMPP 5.6.8 and in its portable version. But, since I can only reproduce this problem in Yii2-powered project and everything goes as good as it can in Yii1-powered application or under pure PHP, then there must be some sort of nasty devil inside.

Can someone help here or at least shed some light, where should I start looking for?

Comment: Idk actually. I have `XAMPP Version 1.8.3` with `php 5.5.11`. Tested and for me php fatal errors handled properly. So it must be your local installation problem, try another xamp or vagrant box maybe.

Comment: have you set debug variable to true in web/index.php   `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');`

Comment: @arkoak Yes, of course! :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that on certain environments, when Yii2 handles a missing variable error, it shows an error at the bottom of the debugger.

`Warning: var_export does not handle circular references in ~/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseVarDumper.php on line 187`

Maybe that error is causing your environment to die on this.
However this seems to be a bug.

Also, I found a workaround using the solution found in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3327).
It's not pretty, but is a solution.

**Edit:** A patch for this issue was released. [See here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8723#issuecomment-129171206)